# How can I understand the domain of the page that includes a javascript residing on my site?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a site that provides my customers with an easy way to use a javascript component that I built myself: this way is to include a javascript reference to my script, which then resides on my server. a bit like including google analytics. But I need to figure out which sites my script is running on, how can I figure it out? can I know the domain in which this script is included by analyzing the request? (the JavaScript code is produced dynamically in asp.net so I have access to the request, to the server variables etc).
I tried with Urlreferrer but some browsers cancel it.
thanks

Comment: Maybe you would like to use real time database for storing the client information (like which site is using, which browser etc) upon connection.

Comment: I don't care about client. I would understand the domains (my customers) where the script are installed in order to block the use in some case